# Should I use IActionResult in a get request that returns a json object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET API that goes as following

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetModel")]
public async Model GetModel(string modelId)
{
    return _service.GetModel(modelId);
}
```

and a client that goes as following

```
public async Model GetModel(string modelId)
{
    var uri = $"api/Model/GetModel?modelId={modelId}";
    return await _httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Model>(uri);
}
```

I am not using `IActionResult` or status codes. I am also not doing any exception handling in the API. (I am just taking appropriate action on the client if the model is returned null.)

Do I need to use `IActionResult` or status codes? What is the best practice for this? This is a high-level question so I would appreciate it if you were to elaborate on the concepts.

Comment: There is an entire article about this located here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types I prefer to return `IActionResult` as you can define the status codes for return.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it here.: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/action-results
this explains in great detail as to why and what best practices are.

If your handler method returns more than one type of action result depending on conditions, you will need to broaden the return type of the method to ActionResult or IActionResult.